# What is the meaning of the highlighted sentence given down below from the conversation?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Family eating pork chop.

Dad: Wasn't it good kids? Huh?

Son: Frozen in the middle.

Dad: Hey! Hey! Hey! Your mother worked hard all day.This was a good meal alright?

Christ, There is striving kids in Africa fighting off wildebeest **who would kill for a medley of pork. I mean those kids would eat each other.**

Comment: I means "don't grumble about the good food we give you, when there are hungry people in the world."

Comment: This is a peculiar conversation. For one thing, if a pork chop was really 'frozen in the middle' it would be unsafe to eat and so a legitimate cause of complaint!

Comment: Is the family all eating one pork chop? No wonder the kids are complaining.

Comment: Wildebeest are herbivores, but a search turned up one site that said "Wildebeest Attack Prompts Calls from Gnu-Control Advocates".